# Send email after creating New Item in External List

Tags: 2013, email, external-list, bdc

I am using SP 2013 and I have an external list. But when I created a new item, I want to send e-mail to the specific people.

Workflow is disabled for external lists. So can we create a new method in BDC Model with Visual Studio for sending emails?